# When closing a Eureka Clients, the RestTemplate with @LoadBalanced will continue call the closing service, how fixed it?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I use Eureka and Spring Cloud;

Start 2 Eureka Clients;

When closing a Eureka Clients, the Eureka client unregister from Eureka server need a little time (3-5 minutes);

the RestTemplate with @LoadBalanced will continue call the closing service, how fixed it?

Comment: Please don't post questions in multiple places.  See my response here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2041

Answer (score 1):

I believe a `Eureka` client app doesn't go through the `Eureka` server to get metadata about another `Eureka` client app for every request. This means a `Eureka` client app keeps a cache of the registry, if another `Eureka` client app deregisters, its metadata might still be caches in the previous client until it syncs with the `Eureka` server.

This behavior might be configurable through one or a combination these settings:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds:
```